# Upload script not finding directory

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp

This is my upload script

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
admin_page();

$fields = array('title', 'description');
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $fields) == true){
    $errors[] = 'All fields are required';
    break 1;
}
}

if(!empty($errors)){
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
else{
#remove slashes from content
$title = stripslashes($_POST["title"]);
$description = stripslashes($_POST["description"]);


if(isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && isset($_FILES["image"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    ############ Edit settings ##############
    $UploadMainDirectory    = '/center/downloads/';
    $UploadImageDirectory   = '/center/images/';
    ##########################################

    //check if this is an ajax request
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
        die();
    }

    if ($_FILES["FileInput"]["size"] > 1024*1024*1024) {
        die("Main file size is too big!");
    }

    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 1*1024*1024) {
        die("Image size is too big!");
    }

    switch(strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['type']))
    {
        //allowed file types
        case 'image/png': 
        case 'image/gif': 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        case 'image/pjpeg':
        case 'text/plain':
        case 'application/x-zip-compressed':
        case 'application/x-rar-compressed':
        case 'application/octet-stream':
        case 'application/zip':
        case 'application/rar':
        case 'application/x-zip':
        case 'application/x-rar':
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported main file!'); //output error
    }

    switch(strtolower($_FILES['image']['type']))
    {
        //allowed file types
        case 'image/png': 
        case 'image/gif': 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported image file!'); //output error
    }

    $File_Name          = strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['name']);
    $File_Ext           = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); //get file extention
    $Random_Number      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be added to name.
    $NewFileName        = $Random_Number.$File_Ext; //new file name

    $ImageName          = strtolower($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $ImageExt           = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.')); //get file extention
    $NewImageName       = $Random_Number.$ImageExt; //new file name

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadMainDirectory.$NewFileName ) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $UploadImageDirectory.$NewImageName ))
       {
        $fields = array('type', 'name', 'description', 'file', 'image');

        $upload_data = array(
        'type'           => $_POST['type'],
        'name'           => $_POST['title'],
        'description'    => $_POST['description'],
        'file'           => $NewFileName,
        'image'          => $NewImageName,
        );
        array_walk($upload_data, 'array_sanitize');
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($upload_data)) . '`';
        $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $upload_data) . '\'';

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `downloads` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");

        die('Success! File Uploaded.');
    }else{
        die('Error uploading Files!');
    }

}
else
{
    die('Something went wrong!');
}
}
?>
```

My problem is that the script is not working, on `localhost` gives me an error that says that the directory does not exist but it exists.
I've uploaded the script on my host, but even there i get the error ...
My directory looks like this

[image]

How i can fix this ?

Comment: *which* directory does not exists? What is the directory you're getting the error message for?

Comment: where is child directory "downloads" i.e. your path is /center/downloads/

Comment: I have all the directories, both `/center/downloads/` and `/center/images/` but the script is not finding any of them

Comment: Is the above code exist in file adm_download_center_process.php and center directory also exist in same directory ??? If yes, then remove "/" before "/center/downloads/" i.e. try with only "center/downloads/"

Comment: @PankajGarg This worked, please write this as answer in order to accept it :)

Comment: @S0DDesign : answered!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the above code exist in file adm_download_center_process.php and center directory also exist in same directory ??? If yes, then remove "/" before "/center/downloads/" i.e. try with only "center/downloads/" –

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `/dir/dir/....` that means you want to use (for windows): `C:/dir/dir/...` and for linux `/dir/dir/...`  {{C - put there current drive letter site operates on}}. This is calles *absolute path* what you wanted to use is *relative path* the path that starts where you are not from the given location.

So you should have

```
############ Edit settings ##############
$UploadMainDirectory    = 'center/downloads/';
$UploadImageDirectory   = 'center/images/';
##########################################
```

what would be translated as relative path to `current_directory/center/downloads/` and be usable by application.